# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE CSV Import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, csv-import

CSF recommends disabling "local-infile=0" in my.cnf however this is blocking me and any user on server from importing CSV files in PHPmyAdmin. Any way to keep that disabled but allow CSV import if the question is possible as well?

Comment: What's CSF? I doubt there's a way to disable local-infile while maintaining the ability to load from a file.

Comment: CSF is ConfigServer Firewall check it http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html